# How do I display a built-in row view with an item already checked?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, listadapter

I'm using the Xamarin built-in row view `SimpleListItemSingleChoice`.

I want to display the view with an item already checked, but it isn't working.

My ListAdapter gets as input, a list of objects that have an IsChosen property, so that it knows which object should be selected:

```
public MySproutListAdapter (Activity context, IList<Sprout> mySprouts) : base ()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.sprouts = mySprouts;
    }
```

The `GetView()` method is as follows:

```
public override Android.Views.View GetView (int position, 
                                            Android.Views.View convertView, 
                                            Android.Views.ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //Try to reuse convertView if it's not  null, otherwise inflate it from our item layout
        var view = (convertView ?? 
            context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemSingleChoice, parent, false)) as LinearLayout;

        var textLabel = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);

        textLabel.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(sprouts[position].sproutText);

//I thought this line would display the view with the correct item's radio 
//button selected, but it doesn't seem to.
            textLabel.Selected = sprouts[position].IsChosen;

            return view;
        }
```

I looked at custom definitions for selected list views, but as it's a built-in view, I thought a custom definition must be over-complicating things.
How do I make the built-in view display the selected item correctly?

Comment: Was wrong, provided working sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to check item from inside the adapter. You need to call ListView.SetItemChecked(selectedItemIndex, true).
[Link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview's_appearance/#Selecting_Items_Programmatically).

EDIT.

Sorry I was wrong. You are setting Checked == true on inner TextView but not on the item itself. Here is working sample:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace TestSimpleListItemSingleChoice
{
    [Activity (Label = "TestSimpleListItemSingleChoice", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            var adapter = new TestAdapter (this);
            adapter.Add ("test1");
            adapter.Add ("test2");
            adapter.Add ("test3");
            adapter.Add ("test4");
            FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1).Adapter = adapter;
        }
    }

    public class TestAdapter : ArrayAdapter<string>{
        public TestAdapter(Context context) : base(context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemSingleChoice, Android.Resource.Id.Text1){
        }
        public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var view = base.GetView (position, convertView, parent);
            ((CheckedTextView)view).Checked = position == 1;
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried this code, but get an error in Xamarin Studio, on the call to the base.GetView (can't call abstract method).

Comment: I read your comment that checked=true must be set on the ListView, not on each item, so I added this code to the Activity (not the Adapter):  myListView.SetItemChecked(chosenIndex, true);

Comment: So your answer did help me to fix this problem :-)  Do you want to change the code in the answer, or does it really work for you?  I am happy to mark this as the correct answer, if I'm sure that the code snippet is also correct.

Comment: @SList I tested this code in Xamarin Studio and it worked well for me.  Could you give me more details about error you are getting?

Comment: @SList both approaches are fine. ListView.SetItemChecked(selectedItemIndex, true) is a generic way and using adapter is specific to SimpleListItemSingleChoice template that is not really good. I just decided to give you more information about possible options.

Comment: Do you use ArrayAdapter<string> as a base class for your adapter?

Comment: The error was that the base.GetView can't be called because it is an abstract method. My base class is BaseAdapter<myDefinedClass>

Comment: I guess this is the reason for the error.  I don't want to let the question creep too far, so I'll mark it as fixed (and read some more about adapters).  There's quite a lot of information here that will hopefully be useful to someone else.  Many thanks for your help.